# PHP - overlaying an image on another image

Tags: php, imagemagick

I have an image (think a photograph of a tree) and I want to put a 'play' arrow on it. I have 1000s of images to do this too. Is there a better way to do this than with imagemagick?

Comment: gd functions you can use, but imagick is the best, wht the issue with the imagick ?

Comment: first step: you need to search the internet, how to overlay an image. After you successfully doing that, next process would be to automate it to your 1000s of images. Go try that step out, if you stuck, back here with specific problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use a "plugin" instead of writing your own codes. I'll suggest Asido, it can use imagemagick, gd, etc.
http://sourceforge.net/projects/asido/

Answer (score 1):

May be this code helps you... in this i got a border around the images

```
$water_mark = imagecreatefrompng('your/image/path.png');   
$water_mark_width = imagesx($water_mark);   
$water_mark_height = imagesy($water_mark);   
$image = imagecreatetruecolor($water_mark_width, $water_mark_height);   
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg('image_path.jpg');   
$size = getimagesize('image_path.jpg');   
$dest_x = $size[0] - $water_mark_width - 0;   
$dest_y = $size[1] - $water_mark_height - 0;   
imagecopymerge($image, $water_mark, $dest_x, $dest_y, 0,0, $watermark_width, $watermark_height, 100);
```